# What size is the vial vets use to take the blood of a domestic cat?

Tags: cats, veterinarian

If a cat goes to the vet, they might take its blood. How big is the vial they use? I assume it can't be the same size as the vial they use for humans because cats are so much smaller and have less total blood. My cat probably has only 750 mL of blood, if that (and he is quite a large housecat) but I have about 6 L of blood

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vials do come in different sizes and I suspect will vary by manufacturer and laboratory. Easier to answer is the amount of blood needed for various tests.

To run chemistries (usually serum is needed), we have 4 mL tubes, in which the lab likes us to put at least 1 mL, preferably more. The amount of serum needed will depend on the number of tests you need run – to assess a few electrolytes, maybe a BUN/creatinine to look at the kidneys, and a couple of liver enzymes, not much serum will be needed, but if you want to do lots of other tests then obviously more blood will need to be taken.

To run complete blood counts (CBC) for cats our standard tubes are the same size as chemistry tubes, in which the lab requires 1 mL of blood. These tubes contain EDTA to stop the blood from clotting, and the important thing with these tubes is that there is the correct ratio of blood to EDTA, otherwise the results will be skewed. As cats can be tricky to get blood from sometimes, we do also have mini tubes that only require 0.5 mL (or at a stretch 0.3 mL) on which a full CBC can still be run – but the lab can sometimes get upset if you are too stingy with the blood you submit. Some other tests are run on whole blood and in these cases additional blood may be required.

Other more specialized testing such as for clotting times does require other blood tubes.

For your "standard" cat bloodwork including a chemistry, CBC, and T4, the vet will need to draw at least 1.5-2 mL minimum.

For reference I currently use Idexx and the details on their tubes are shown in their [Sample Collection Tube Guide](https://www.idexxbioanalytics.com/hubfs/IBA_RE23%20ReF%20Lab%20Tube%20Guide%20Horizontal%20RE.pdf).

Comment: Do you really mean 1 milliliter with "1 mL"? That seems to be so very little compared to how much blood is usually drawn from humans. If the lab tests are reliable with such a small amount, I wonder why they still draw so much from humans.

Comment: you have this amount for every single test I think, and most test be done 2 times to eliminate failure. One "test" could then include the test of many different things, for example with blood cells, red blood cells, glucose level, every single type of antibody, and so on

Comment: @Elmy Yes, 1 milliliter. Not sure why so much larger volumes are obtained from humans, when the amount of blood needed for many tests is on the order of microlitres.